# Unable to access frames by FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever using OPTION_CLOSEST

Tags: android, video, android-ffmpeg

I have an mp4 video on my device whose frames I'm trying to extract using FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever. I am able to retrieve a frame by

```
mmr.getFrameAtTime(time*1000000L)
```

I am trying to retrieve multiple frames in a time range using

```
for(i in 0..frames step 1 ){
            val frame = mmr.getFrameAtTime(i*1000000L/fps!!, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST)
            if(frame != null)
             bitMapList.add(frame)
        }
```

Here I am getting all the frames as null when using the `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST`

When I omit the option, I get frames, all being same.
The `fps` is retrieved using

```
fps = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_FRAMERATE).toInt()
```

Can someone please guide me how to go about correctly here?

Comment: I am looking for solution to this issue